# Panel not Adding to the main Frame

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have a main frame and 3 panels. I want to add those 3 panels to the main frame. However, only 2 of them are getting added. The third one is not. I am not able to figure out why. Can someone help?

```
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth=GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.gridheight=GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weightx=gbc.weighty=1;      
        add(topPanel1, gbc);
        add(bottomPanel1, gbc);
        gbc.gridheight=GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        add(buttonsPanel, gbc);
```

the above code is the constructor of a frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `gridx` or `gridy` value, according to your desired layout.
E.g. if you want to layout the components vertically do something like this:

```
gbc.gridx=0;
gbc.gridy=0;
add(topPanel1, gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
add(bottomPanel1, gbc);
gbc.gridy++;
add(buttonsPanel, gbc);
```

If you do not set the `gridx/y` values the behavior is unspecified (sometimes it may work).

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `gbc.gridheight=GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;` statement if you want to add three panels one after one.